# MySQL Select Query can not get the id for each day in a row

Tags: mysql, select

I have a problem is I can not get the id from each day in table result in each row. My table in phpMyAdmin is like this:

```
  ------------------------------------
  |   Date_id  |        Date         |
  ------------------------------------
  |    1       |  2014-05-13         |
  |    2       |  2014-06-04         |
  |    3       |  2014-07-09         |
  |    4       |  2014-08-13         |
  |    5       |  2014-09-12         |
  |    6       |  2014-10-15         |
  |    7       |  2014-11-19         |
  |    8       |  2014-12-10         |
  |    9       |  2015-01-14         |
  |    10      |  2015-02-11         |
  |    11      |  2015-03-10         |
  |    12      |  2015-04-15         |
  |    13      |  2015-05-12         |
  |    14      |  2015-06-12         |
  ------------------------------------
```

When I write code php to get the `Date_id` to edit but it still display the 1st row is only one id for each column the same and the second, third row... is also display only one id. My Tables like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Year  | Jan | Feb | Mar | April | May | June | July | Aug | Sept | Oct | Nov | Dec |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2014    |     |     |     |       | 13  | 04   | 07   | 13  | 12   | 15  | 19  | 10  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2015    | 14  | 11  | 10  |  15   | 12  | 12   |      |     |      |     |     |     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my query code that I had use it:

```
select year(`Date`) as `year`,Date_id,
   max(case when month(date) = 1 then day(`date`) end) as Jan,
   max(case when month(date) = 2 then day(`date`) end) as Feb,
   max(case when month(date) = 3 then day(`date`) end) as Mar,
   max(case when month(date) = 4 then day(`date`) end) as Apr,
   max(case when month(date) = 5 then day(`date`) end) as May,
   max(case when month(date) = 6 then day(`date`) end) as Jun,
   max(case when month(date) = 7 then day(`date`) end) as Jul,
   max(case when month(date) = 8 then day(`date`) end) as Aug,
   max(case when month(date) = 9 then day(`date`) end) as Sep,
   max(case when month(date) = 10 then day(`date`) end) as Oct,
   max(case when month(date) = 11 then day(`date`) end) as Nov,
   max(case when month(date) = 12 then day(`date`) end) as Dec
from table t
group by year(date)
order by year(date)
```

**My Expected result is it will be display as my tables and it will get the id from each day.

How can I write the query? Thanks you.**

Comment: I guess you need to use `Date_id` in `group by` clause

Comment: can you give an example.

Comment: I mean that how can you add in my query. Please add it because when I write it error. Just query add code me again on group by clause.

Comment: how come for July 2014 the value in the table is 07 should't it be 09 ? and if not then what is the logic behind that ?

Comment: @JonhKevin In your query there is `date_id` but you I can't see and `,` after that. So Add `,` and group by `date_id`

Comment: @Siva I am sorry I wrote forgot ,.

Comment: which date_id do you want? for each month you mean? please make it clear with expected result table.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine but there is a small issue. You are using a reserved key word `dec` which is breaking the query. You need to backtick it , here is the revised query

```
select year(`Date`) as `year`,Date_id,
   max(case when month(date) = 1 then day(`date`) end) as Jan,
   max(case when month(date) = 2 then day(`date`) end) as Feb,
   max(case when month(date) = 3 then day(`date`) end) as Mar,
   max(case when month(date) = 4 then day(`date`) end) as Apr,
   max(case when month(date) = 5 then day(`date`) end) as May,
   max(case when month(date) = 6 then day(`date`) end) as Jun,
   max(case when month(date) = 7 then day(`date`) end) as Jul,
   max(case when month(date) = 8 then day(`date`) end) as Aug,
   max(case when month(date) = 9 then day(`date`) end) as Sep,
   max(case when month(date) = 10 then day(`date`) end) as Oct,
   max(case when month(date) = 11 then day(`date`) end) as Nov,
   max(case when month(date) = 12 then day(`date`) end) as `Dec`
from test t
group by `year`
order by `year`
```

You can takeout `Date_id` from the select list if you dont want.

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5da086/7)**

Comment: It does no harm, but this particular ORDER BY is redundant.

Comment: Ah I see @Strawberry what you mean I did not notice it the `year(Date) as year` is already in select does not make sense to have redundant code in order by. Let me update, BTW good catch and very keen observation.